# Creating new whatsapp numbers with API

Tags: twilio, message, whatsapp

I am building a service where we need to create a new phone number to each new account and later act as its Whatsapp intermediary. So every new user can have their own Whatsapp number and see chats (and interract with them) in our external app. Basically a client for whatsapp numbers. Is there a way to do it with Twilio or Vonage? I tried to but it seems like it allows to build such functionalities only with one, WhatsappBusiness account. But it doesn't allow to scale new numbers programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do have an alternative process for [creating accounts that service other businesses through WhatsApp if you are an independent software vendor or system integrator](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039305933-Integrating-WhatsApp-with-Independent-Software-Vendors-ISV-and-System-Integrators-SI-). However, it's still not an API process. I believe this is because there is an amount of back and forth between you, Twilio and Facebook to set up, review, and approve each business account and number.

The restrictive nature of this is on Facebook's side, since they have stricter rules for how WhatsApp can be used to engage users. So I don't imagine any partner will be able to offer this process entirely through an API.